# R Packages - What is the file 'zzz.R' used for?

Tags: r, package

I'm planning to condense some of my code into a package, and was looking at the source of a few published packages on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) as a guide. I notice many packages include the file `R\zzz.R`, so I presume there must be some convention surrounding this.

However, I cannot find any mention of `zzz.R` in the official [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) guide. What is this file for, and do I need to include one in my package? Why is it named the way it is - why not `zzzz.R`?

Comment: 3 identical letters is a world-wide well accepted convention, 4 would sound silly, no?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a file where one usually puts actions on load of the package.  It is tradition/convention that it's called zzz.R and could be called anything.R

You only need to include this if you want you package to do something out of the ordinary when it loads.  Keep looking at what people put in there and you'll begin to get a sense of what they're used for.

Comment: These links are broken. Those coming late to this look at this new home http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html for Hadley's package book  (the "When you do need side-effects" section).

Comment: I think an important confusion to clear up is whether R at some point of time loaded files in alphabetical order. Or, if R doesn't, does `pkgload::load_code`?

Comment: I believe (but would need to check) that R does indeed concatenate all .R files in alphabetical order before loading, so stuff in `zzz.R` is in fact evaluated last (unless you're using an Estonian locale :-) )

Answer (score 15):

This zzz.R file was also mentioned by Hadley Wickham in his book "R packages", at the bottom of "When you do need side-effects" section.

https://r-pkgs.org/Code.html#when-you-do-need-side-effects

*If you use .onLoad(), consider using .onUnload() to clean up any side effects. By convention, .onLoad() and friends are usually saved in a file called R/zzz.R. (Note that .First.lib() and .Last.lib() are old versions of .onLoad() and .onUnload() and should no longer be used.)*